# Will revoking a current APNs key break a live app?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have an app in the App Store that uses push notifications via Firebase Cloud Messaging. I created an APNs key for it at the time. I no longer have the key and was planning on releasing a new app. I tried to create a new key but the Devloper portal said I have reached the limit of keys for this service. If revoke the old key will it break the app I already have in the App Store? What's the best solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your app will continue to function on the app store, however will be unable to receive push notifications until you replace the old key with the new key. Your APNS key is specific to your development team and not to the app itself. You won't need to update the existing app after switching the keys. The only info that APNS needs from the app is the bundle identifier.

Comment: So I won't need to replace the .p8 file in the Firebase console once I revoke the old key?

Comment: You should have to replace the .p8 file, since that's the key: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_token-based_connection_to_apns

Comment: Great, glad to have helped!